# JS triggered file download messes up accented characters

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm triggering a HTML file download using JavaScript this way:

```
var pom = document.createElement('a');
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(htmlContent));
pom.setAttribute('download', 'download.html');
pom.click();
```

This works fine, but if there are accented characters like é, í, ó, ú, etc. in the `htmlContent`, then the downloaded document does not display those properly (they are replaced by strange symbols).

How do I trigger a file download for text that has such special characters using just JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to HTML-escape any extended-ascii characters (codes larger than 127).

I've used Lo-Dash to convert the original string to an array and map the array to HTML-escaped characters as required -- you can do that however you wish.

```
var htmlContent = "é, í, ó, ú, etc.";
htmlContent = _.map(_.toArray(htmlContent), function (char) {
    var code = char.charCodeAt(0);
    if (code > 128) { return "&#" + code + ";"; }
    return char;
}).join("");

var pom = document.createElement('a');
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(htmlContent));
pom.setAttribute('download', 'download.html');
pom.click();
```