# Special character (Æ, Ø, ø, Å, å, Ä, ä, Ö, ö) in downloaded word file getting formatted to ASCI values in javascript

Tags: javascript, download, href, accent-insensitive

I am downloading the macro enabled dotm file. This file is stored inside the server where the foreign characters are showing up fine, but when I download the same file through mu JS code to local its messing up the characters.URL is the file path I am passing here.

Example is NEERGÅRDSPARKEN to NEERG%C5RDSPARKEN and RØDOVRE to R%D8DOVRE.
url is where the macro enabled file path is passed.

```
const fileName = '1109801867_2024-02-01_15-24-22.dotm'; 
const anchor = document.createElement("a");

anchor.download = fileName;
anchor.href = url;
anchor.href = anchor.href.slice(5);

document.body.appendChild(anchor);

anchor.click();

document.body.removeChild(anchor);
```

[JS triggered file download messes up accented characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976689/js-triggered-file-download-messes-up-accented-characters) is the path I found something (I got this example from another search which wont work here in my case as I am passing url in href.) where it does not help me here.

Comment: In the linked question it makes sense that characters are broken because `encodeURIComponent` is used. I see you use some `url` variable. Is it also some encoded data or is it a real link? Does it work if you paste this url in the address bar?

Comment: The problem is most likely not with the JS, but with the webserver (to which the `url` is pointing) not serving the file with the correct [content-type header](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/). Does it work if you browse to the `url` directly?

Comment: What is the purpose of `anchor.href = anchor.href.slice(5);`?